# How to branch a TFS Team project that has no branch folder

Tags: tfs, version-control, versioning

i have a Team project like this:

```
DefaultCollection
    -Project 1      
    -Project 2    
    -Project 3
    -Somefile.txt 
    -Somefile2.doc
```

All files and projects are in the root of the Team Project. I don't have "trunk" and "branches" folder.  How can i create a new branch for the entire project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new Team Project(DefaultCollection-Branch1).

Right click on DefaultCollection-Branch1 > Branching and Merging > Convert to branch.

Right click on DefaultCollection > Branching and Merging > Merge > Choose Target to be DefaultCollection-Branch1

Comment: There is a reparenting step that you forgot. I posted it in my follow up answer.

Answer (score 11):

I find that creating a new folder inside the team project and moving everything inside is an easier solution, you can then convert that new folder into a branch (which will be your main branch) and create new branches as required.

Steps are:

1. Open your solution explorer
2. In your team project create a new folder (i.e. Main)

[image]

3. Right-click on all other folders (and files in the root) and select 'Move', select your 'Main' folder

[image]
[image]

4. Check-in your changes
5. Convert your new folder into a branch

[image]

Comment: Best option by far, recommend this instead of the accepted answer! Easier and straightforward.

Comment: This doesn't really do what the OP asked for. It creates an additional folder level. Is there any way to avoid doing that?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sunil's steps, you have to reparent your branch after the merge. So the full steps are:

1. Create a new Team Project(DefaultCollection-Branch1).
2. Right click on DefaultCollection-Branch1 > Branching and Merging > Convert to branch.
3. Right click on DefaultCollection > Branching and Merging > Merge > Choose Target to be DefaultCollection-Branch1
4. Right click on DefaultCollection-Branch1 > Branching and Merging > Reparent, choose DefaultCollection (notice that it says branch relationship is *merge*).

Comment: I can't reparent. There are no branches to choose.