# TFS Undo convert Team Project to branch

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, tfsbuild

I found the solution about how to create a new branch wit multiple foders, thanks to this post .
[How to branch a TFS Team project that has no branch folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696958/how-to-branch-a-tfs-team-project-that-has-no-branch-folder)

But before I can do that, I made a mistake that i try to fix.

[image]

I converted the Team Project "XSun" as branch and i want to roll back this action.

How can I do that ?

Comment: I found the solution, I just have to convert the branch as normal folder and it is ok

Comment: you could share the solution as answer, so that others can see at first glance that this is a thread that already has an answer without spending more time helping you search for the answer